# Fields overlapping subreport in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, floating, subreport

Some fields in my report are overlapping my subreport. I searched this forum and most of the answers are to set the position to "floating", but the fields are already with the position set to "floating". Is there any other option to fix this?

Comment: The subreport is in a other detail band or the same as the fields ?

Comment: @DavidH. No, it's in the same band, summary band.

Comment: The best way is to set the fields property as `Fix Relative to Top` and also for the subReport

Comment: @DavidH. That didn't work, but I just found the solution. I drew a line between the subreport and the fields beneath it, and now it's working perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was draw a line between the subreport and the fields beneath it, and now it's working perfectly.